# Proving - set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

Is ***x∈ ((A\C) ∩ B)*** **∪** ***((A\B) ∩ C)*** same as ***x∈ (AΔC)\B*** ?

I need to prove that $(A\backslash (B \cup C))\cup (C\backslash (A\cup B))$ $=$ $(A\Delta C)\backslash B $ and using *'Let x∈... ...'* method I get to the point where  x∈ ((A\C) ∩ B) ∪ ((A\B) ∩ C), so is that same as x∈ (AΔC)\B?

Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: You made a mistake, if you got there, because it is not the same.

Comment: Hint: If you want the "Let$x \in ..."$ method do something like this: 
Let $x \in ((A\(B \cup C)) \cup (C\(A \cup B))$. Case 1: $x \in ((A\(B \cup C))$.This implies that $x \in A\B$ and $x \in A\C$, hence $x \notin C$. In total $x \in$ left side of your equation.
Now try the 2nd case and the other inclusion.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I knew there was some kind of mistake. Do you know how I can prove the equation?

Comment: Thank you so much, that will probably help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the properties of unions, intersections and difference of two sets to prove that, without involving elements of the set and much calculation.

LHS = $
(A\(B\cup C))\cup (C\(A\cup B))$

=$(A\cap(B\cup C)^c)\cup(C\cap (A\cup B)^c)$

=$(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap A^c \cap B^c)$

=$((A\cap C^c)\cup (A^c \cap C))\cap B^c$

=$(A\Delta C)\B$

=RHS

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank you very much! :D It seems a lot easier that way, but right now we are supposed to use the "Let x∈..." method.